# Unable to start Celery on OS X Mavericks

Tags: django, redis, celery

I want to use Celery and Redis in a Django 1.6.2 application I'm developing on a Mac running OS X 10.9.5.  To start, I'm working through the [First Steps with Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) document.  However, when I try to start Celery as shown in the doc using this command:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

I get this error:

```
[<date>: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://127.0.0.1:6379//: Error 61 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused..  Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

From my research, it would appear that the problem may be occuring because I didn't start the Redis server.  When I look at my processes, I don't see it running.  However, the Celery document didn't discuss start the server and I don't see the "redis-server" command anywhere in the redis branch of my virtual environment.

I installed redis with this command:

```
pip install -U celery[redis]
```

I then added /usr/lib to my DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

I also added the following line to my Django settings:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
```

The Python script I'm trying to run is the example shown in the documentation:

```
# tasks.py
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I tried using "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1" but that didn't fix the problem.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... it's looking like doing "pip install celery[redis]" doesn't install Redis, just the bindings Celery needs to talk to it.  I'm looking into that right now.

Comment: Yes, I need to install Redis.  Sorry for the stupid question, folks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem was that I hadn't actually installed Redis.  These two articles are helpful:


[Compiling a Web Development Environment on Mac OS X](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/redis/)

[How to install redis on OS X](http://www.richardsumilang.com/blog/2014/04/04/how-to-install-redis-on-os-x/)